# how to predict or get default fullCalendar firstDay

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, momentjs

For some reason, I need to know the first day of week used by full calendar even if it is not specified in the calendar options.

The documentation say :

> The default value depends on the current lang.

I could not find a way to get the computed first day, neither the way is computed.
I assume it's the same that moment.js local. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are searching for something like this:

```
var firstDay = $('#your-selector').fullCalendar('getView').start;
var lastDay = $('#your-selector').fullCalendar('getView').end;
```

That's in the weekView.

If you need to select first and last only in the visible days you have this properties:

```
var firstDay = $('#your-selector').fullCalendar('getView').visStart;
var lastDay = $('#your-selector').fullCalendar('getView').visEnd;
```

Comment: Not very practicle, because you have to switch your view mode if you are not in week view mode. I wish there were something nicer

Comment: There aren't no more getters for this purpose. If you need to catch the first day of a week in the monthView, you need to manually iterate the table with jQuery/javascript. That's hard and very unsecure (the tables painted by fullcalendar are very unpredictable)

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things with moment.js

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
var endOfWeek   = moment().endOf('week').toDate();
```

maybe like this ?

Comment: In this case I will have default of moment and not of fullcalendar !

Comment: yes I also updated my comment, and you still not answering my question I am not asking about moment() startDate default but about fullcalendar default.